# Iterating through std queue

Tags: c++, iterator, queue, foreach

I'm trying to use BOOST_FOREACH for iterating through the std::queue. But there isn't iterators in that class cause I have an error:

```
std::queue<std::string> someList;
BOOST_FOREACH(std::string temp, someList)
{
   std::cout << temp;
}

>no matching function for call to begin(...)
>no type named ‘iterator’ in ‘class std::queue<std::basic_string<char> >’
```

I need in structure like: the first comes, the first goes away.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259099/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) supports efficient insert and removal at the beginning and end of the data structure.  You can do queue operations manually using `push_back` and `pop_front`.

A queue uses a deque internally by default.  It's a wrapper that only exposes queue operations (hence why you can't iterate over it).  I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493774/why-dont-the-standard-c-container-adaptors-provide-a-clear-function) a while back, and the best answer gave me good insight into the real use of `std::queue`.  One should use `std::queue` not because one needs a queue, but to make it clear that only queue-like operations are legal on a given data structure.  It sounds like you need more freedom than that, so go with deque, list, or some other structure with O(1) insert and remove at both ends.

Comment: I thought queue is simpler (perf + mem) than deque. But after your answer (and verified through header file), I think there is no difference in perf and memory regardless of queue or deque, except restrictions over some operations in case of Queue.

Answer (score 4):

you can use
std::list with push_front and pop_back

Answer (score 1):

`std::queue` is a container adaptor. It uses `std::deque` as the default underlying container. Access to this container isn't possible and thus isn't iteration in any way.

The best way is to use a `std::deque` or `std::list` and manage the queue behaviour yourself. Possibly provide your own wrapper around it.