# Why the std::queue has no method clear()?

Tags: c++, language-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't the standard C++ container adaptors provide a clear function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493774/why-dont-the-standard-c-container-adaptors-provide-a-clear-function)

What is the rationale behind not adding the `clear()` method to the std::queue?
All other containers have it.

I know I can clear a queue like this :

```
std::queue< int > q;
q = std::queue< int >();
```

but this looks better :

```
std::queue< int > q;
q.clear();
```

Comment: @Naveen good catch. It didn't show in the list of possible duplicates

Comment: @Matthieu Did ever worked what? List of possible duplicates? Usually it does ;)

Comment: It never worked for me :/ Perhaps that my titles are not expressive enough :(